# EXCEL: flag a variable based on one example

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In may data I have two columns: organisation Code and flag, I want to create a new variable based on these two. The flag code contains either 0 or 1

The same organisation code can appear many times in the column, but if there are one or more examples of an organisation code having the number 1 in the flag column, I want the new variable  to be 1 in all cases for this provider: even if it is followed by 0 in the flag column in some cases.

Does anyone know how to do this in a formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you have organisation codes in `A2` down and flags in `B2` down then use this formula in `C2` copied down

`IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,1),1,0)`

That will give you a one for all rows where the organisation has any rows with a 1 flag, 0 otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you need (next time, please provide some sample data). There is probably a more eloquent way to do this, but my solution will work.

I assume the following table:

[image: Initial Table]

In `Cell C2` add the following formula:

```
=IF(SUMIF(A$2:A$9;A2;B$2:B$9)>=1;1;0)
```

This assumes your organisations are in `Cells A2 to A9` and your flags are in `Cells B2 to B9`. You will need to change these to fit your table. This formula gives you a `1` if any of the `Flags` for that specific `Organisation` has the value `1` otherwise (assume all `flags` are `0`) it gives you a `0`.

[image]

Note that you may need to change the `semi-colon` separator to a `comma` separator depending on your decimal settings. If it does not work with a `;` change it to a `,`.

Comment: I was preparing exactly this answer! I even used almost the same sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table for it:

- specify your "code" column as "rows"
- set "flag" as "values" and select "max" as aggregation

[image]